# build a dynamic string in sql Equal statement

Tags: sql, string, oracle

I need something to build a string in an sql equal statement, composed by two part, the first one choosed by me and the second one dynamically generated by a query

```
select * from table
where param1= 'test' + (select distinct param2 from table2 where ...)
```

the second select always return only one record of course.
So the where clause should be `where param1='test'+param2`

I tried concat function but it doesn't seem the correct way; any suggestion?

Comment: its not java the concatenation syntax is || here

Comment: `where param1 = (select distinct 'test' || param2 from table2 where ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle uses the ANSI standard `||` operator for string concatenation.  So, use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE param1 = 'test' || (SELECT DISTINCT param2 FROM table2 WHERE ...);
```

The `CONCAT` function should also work here:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE param1 = CONCAT('test', (SELECT DISTINCT param2 FROM table2 WHERE ...));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table
where param1= 'test' || (select distinct param2 from table2 where ...)
```